# Telegram Webhook in Rails: How to view JSON updates with MVC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model-view-controller, telegram, telegram-webhook

I have set my telegram webhook to go to my Webhook controller in rails app. How do I view the incoming JSON information? I know I need a route `get 'webhooks/webhook'`

** edit **
I replaced my route with  `post webhooks/webhook` 
I have a controller called webhook

```
def webhook
    params['webhook']
  end
```

I have a Webhook view with `<% @webhooks %>`.

This is a lot more straightforward in PHP but I’m not sure how this should work in Rails(MVC). Thanks in advance!

Comment: For setting up a webhook you need a POST resource, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: oh, ok. I want to be able to view all of the updates on a page. So I need to do post  'webhooks/webhook'  ?

Comment: In such case, I guess then yes, it sends you data, and you receive, when `params['webhook']` comes the you're able to perform any action you need.

Comment: so i changed the route to post and I tried to go to mywebsite.com/webhooks/webhook and I'm getting "No route matches [GET] "/webhooks/webhook". Do I need to add something else in the routes?

Comment: I'd like to know what changes you made and how you setted the webhook, because the message still shows a request to a GET resource.

Comment: All i did was go to my routes file and switch out the get for post

Comment: When you set up the webhook it uses the route you specify, in your case you're trying to access manually through your browser to such route, why?

Comment: Before I go further with sorting the updates, I'd just like to see them on a page, just as you would see the updates with the getUpdates method. I want to be sure Telegram accepts my ssl and that i'm getting the right info